# Merging DLL into C# Exe, not loading DLL, WHY?

Tags: c#, dll, merge

So i have to load some MetroFramework.Dll's and they work fine when merged , but i also use NAudio.dll that doesn't load at all once merged into the exe file.
I tryed this code first:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
    {

        Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //Get the Name of the AssemblyFile
        var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

        //Load form Embedded Resources - This Function is not called if the Assembly is in the Application Folder
        var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(name));
        if (resources.Count() > 0)
        {
            var resourceName = resources.First();
            using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream == null) return null;
                var block = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(block);
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
```

And it only loads up MetroFramework... not NAudio.dll

Then i changed to my current code:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (arg.Name.StartsWith("NAudio")) { return Assembly.Load(VASBUILD.Properties.Resources.NAudio); }
            else if (arg.Name.StartsWith("MetroFramework")) { return Assembly.Load(VASBUILD.Properties.Resources.MetroFramework); }
            else if (arg.Name.StartsWith("MetroFramework_Design")) { return Assembly.Load(VASBUILD.Properties.Resources.MetroFramework_Design);}
            else if (arg.Name.StartsWith("MetroFramework_Fonts")) { return Assembly.Load(VASBUILD.Properties.Resources.MetroFramework_Fonts); }
            else
            { return null; }

        };
```

so why doesn't it work? does it need to be loaded using another way?

Comment: so this code is in Program.cs, and my form1 class uses metroframework, and my form 2 class uses NAudio, the Program.cs only calls form1, and form 1 calls form2.

Comment: The just-in-time compiler only asks for a DLL if it needs to compile code that uses it.  Just in time.  So set breakpoints on the NAudio calls to verify that they actually execute.  If they do then you'll have a reason to look for other places where naudio.dll might be stored.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds.

Comment: NAudio loads just fine, ive used it for a while in the program, only now that i want to merge my dll's NAudio doesn't seem to be loaded the same way as my design Dll's

Comment: i've seen some comments online about Managed and Unmanaged Dll's using different loading methods